# check if element class have changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've got some JS library, thats on click to the html element changes its class. I would like to write function, that would check if class had been changed, and then add image to this element. Can you help me with this?

thanks!

Comment: what do meant by **"class had been changed"**

Comment: when i click on element its class is changing from <div class="a"> to <div class="b"> and i wanna to add element to this div, when class is b

Comment: as per your comments...please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#elemID").click(function() {
    $("#div").removeClass('a');
    $("#div").addClass('b');
    if ($("#div").attr('class') == 'b') {
        $("#div").append("<p>Hello</p>");
    } 
});
```

Or

```
$("#elemID").click(function() {
    $("#div").removeClass('a');
    $("#div").addClass('b');
    if ($("#div").hasClass('b')) {
        $("#div").append("<p>Hello</p>");
    } 
});
```

Comment: The `if` statement in your second event will always be true.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using jQuery try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get the class that's set on page load
    var current = $('#element').attr('class');
    $('#element').click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).attr('class') != current) {
            // class has been changed, do something
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is an example at jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/kZS8u/1/).

Disclaimer: Without more details about *which* elements have `onclick` event listeners that change *which* elements` class, I cannot give you real working code for you situation. Instead, I can only give you some logic which I just did.

Answer (score 0):

What you can proceed with Krystian is that everytine u click on an element, add a class "say classClicked" to it. Then with the the help of hasClass u can find out the class attached to that element. If is satisfies your condition, add image. 
Or if the class changes on each click and you know the name of the changed class, just check using

if($(this).hasClass("b")){
   do your action
}

Hope this helps.